What is the best npm package to use google maps platform in NEXTJS
I'm currently working on a Next.js project and I'm looking for the best npm package to integrate Google Maps Platform. Despite extensive searching, I haven't been able to find a suitable package or clear documentation on how to implement it. Could someone please provide recommendations or guidance on how to effectively integrate Google Maps Platform into a Next.js project? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.
I tried react-google-maps/api but it doesnt have a guide

If you are using React and NextJS, then you can use https://visgl.github.io/react-google-maps/
react-google-maps/api is currently abandoned by the original owner and their documentation guide is down. So visgl is your best bet.

But I would like to clarify also that asking for recommendations does not meet the Stack Overflow guidelines. So I recommend that you read how to ask here since you are new. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

try to use '@next/third-parties' library:
import { GoogleMapsEmbed } from '@next/third-parties/google'

export default function Page() {
 return (
  <GoogleMapsEmbed
   apiKey="XYZ"
   height={200}
   width="100%"
   mode="place"
   q="Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY"
 />
 )
}

Here is the documentation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/third-party-libraries

Same comment here. Do NOT answer questions that should be closed (it is now) as they are off-topic here. Read [ask] to know what is acceptable and refrain yourself from placing answers on questions that should be closed.

Your issue seems to be related to the lack of documentation for the google-maps-api. I don't know what research you've done but I have something that could be of use.

Medium Article in Implementing Google Maps in Nextjs


The answer yusufie provided looks better.


You wrote your answer after theirs so what was the point of placing a 2nd answer? and 2. Questions like this one should be closed (it is now) as they are off-topic here. Read [ask] to know what is acceptable and refrain yourself from placing answers on questions that should be closed.


I was writing them as the other person wrote theirs. If I saw it was answered, then I would make the post in the first place. And no it is not off-topic. It's directly linked to the person's question. If you saw the resource, it shows you how to implement the library with a lot of documentation. Try it.

Also, it's not a bad thing to have multiple answers to a question. The first answer might not be useful for that person's case, you just wouldn't know. Btw, I was not even asking a question. I posted my answer briefly after Yusufie. Another thing is that the question was not closed, so it was right for me to answer.

The question is off-topic for this website. Proof of that is that it is now closed and not accepting further answers. As I said, you should avoid answering off-topic questions. The quality of your answer is bad too. It doesn't contain any useful information. Read about link-only answers.

I'll avoid it in the future but its not like this place is. I checked your link-only answer page and I did provide context. The question wasn't asking for much so the answer won't be much.
